# работа с контейнером по частям через ссылку с помощью итератора

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть некая функция, принимающая на вход ссылку на вектор размерности `size`:

```
void func(const std::vector<double>& ref);
```

И есть некий вектор размерности `N*size`:

```
std::vector<double> array(N*size);
```

Вопрос: как с помощью итератора можно корректно обработать массив `array` по частям (сначала первые `size` объектов, затем вторые и так `N` раз)?

На выходе хочется получить что-то вроде:

```
for(auto it=array.begin(); it!=array.end(); it+=size){
  //вызов функции
  func(...);//здесь обработка array от элемента i*size до (i+1)*size
}
```

Comment: Исходный вектор должен сохраниться, или ,быть переписанным в N векторов?

Comment: Вам надо переопределить функцию, чтобы она получала на вход не вектор, а два итератора.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow С исходным вектором в функции ничего не происходит - поэтому и ссылка на него сделана константной. Важно только получить доступ к элементам массива.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Нет, переопределить функцию я не могу, это функция внешней библиотеки. Так-то разумеется все бы было элементарно)

Answer (score 1):

Если по условию задания вы не можете переопределить функцию таким образом, чтобы она принимала два итератора вместо ссылки на вектор, то вектор, который будет использоваться в качестве аргумента, в любом случае вам придется создавать. То есть в любом случае этот вектор будет динамически выделять новую память.

Поэтому я не вижу иного подхода кроме прямолинейного.

Вы могли бы написать

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

void func( const std::vector<double> &v )
{
    for ( double x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 0.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 };

    size_t n = 4;
    std::vector<double> tmp;
    tmp.reserve( n );

    for ( auto first = v.begin(), last = v.begin(); first != v.end(); first = last )
    {
        std::advance( last, std::min<size_t>( n, std::distance( last, v.end() ) ) );
        tmp.assign( first, last );
        func( tmp );
    }                     
}
```

Можно ограничить время жизни временного вектора с помощью конструкции `do-while`

Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

void func( const std::vector<double> &v )
{
    for ( double x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 0.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 };

    size_t n = 4;
    do
    {        
        std::vector<double> tmp;
        tmp.reserve( n );

        for ( auto first = v.begin(), last = v.begin(); first != v.end(); first = last )
        {
            std::advance( last, std::min<size_t>( n, std::distance( last, v.end() ) ) );
            tmp.assign( first, last );
            func( tmp );
        }
    } while ( false );        
}
```

Если операция встречается в коде неоднократно, то можно ее оформить в виде отдельной функции. например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

void func( const std::vector<double> &v )
{
    for ( double x : v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void process( const std::vector<double> &v, size_t n )
{
    std::vector<double> tmp;
    tmp.reserve( n );

    for ( auto first = v.begin(), last = v.begin(); first != v.end(); first = last )
    {
        std::advance( last, std::min<size_t>( n, std::distance( last, v.end() ) ) );
        tmp.assign( first, last );

        func( tmp );
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v = { 0.0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 };

    size_t n = 4;

    process( v, n );
}
```

Comment: Vlad, спасибо за ваш ответ. Безусловно, прямой подход работает и у меня. Просто хотелось найти какой-то более элегантный путь, без создания временного объекта, выделение под него памяти и т.д. К примеру вызов той же функции с вектором `N` раз большего размера работает, хоть и безусловно каждый раз пробегает только по началу вектора. И вопрос был как можно двигать "указатель" по вектору, вызывая функцию без использования временных объектов.